# Do bitwise/logical operator math questions belong on Stack Overflow or Math.StackExchange?

Tags: discussion, scope

Bitwise operations are mathematical in nature but are largely relevant in programming. I have a question pertaining to bitwise operators but am not sure which site to post it on.

My question: How can I determine what values of `edx` make `energy` equal to `eax` in the equation `energy = (eax XOR 0x01010101) XOR edx` where `eax = (edx XOR energy) XOR 0x01010101`? Plugging in random numbers and checking results is unfavorable. I need a clear cut solution. All variables are 4 byte unsigned integers represented in hex.

Comment: Is the question specific to an implementation or theory?

Comment: Post a snippet of your question here and we can tell you if it's suitable or not.  Just be braced for constructive criticism.

Comment: @Makoto Will do.

Comment: Answered my own question anyways. You can only `XOR 0x01010101` with a certain value to get `eax`. Just like if `y = 4` in `x + 3 = y` then x will always be 1.

Comment: This particular example is unclear on whether you'd have needed to figure out how to work out the solution for specific `eax` values, or programmatically for arbitrary `eax` values. These potentially would have required very different types of answers, so it's entirely possible that the best site to post it on is different for the two cases. Can you edit your question to make it clearer which one you're interested in?

Comment: re. the question itself: you can see that as there are no carrying operations, you can simply solve it for individual bits (all bits are mutually independent). and then there are only so much possible variants.

Comment: Math.SE seems okay, but Computer Science SE should be fine too.

Comment: @EdwardSeverinsen Off-topic: "You can only `XOR 0x01010101` with a certain value to get `eax`" -- Not really. Note that, in your analogy, there is exactly one solution because *f(x) = x + 3* is a bijection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Adrian [points out](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/367807/do-bitwise-logical-operator-math-questions-belong-on-stack-overflow-or-math-stac#comment588716_367807):

> Math.SE seems okay, but Computer Science SE should be fine too.

The [[boolean-algebra] tag at Math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/boolean-algebra) would be a suitable destination, according to my understanding of [this question on their Meta](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3367/380202) (your question would fall under "'algebra of logic', i.e. basic calculus with truth values"). The evidence is less clear-cut when it comes to CS.SE, but a quick look at [their own [boolean-algebra] tag](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/boolean-algebra) suggests it would be fine to post it there as well. If I were to recommend just one site, I'd say Math.SE.

Comment: Chose this answer because it included a definite answer for where it does belong.

Answer (score 1):

> Title: Do bitwise/logical operator math questions belong on Stack Overflow or Math.StackExchange?

I think the title answers it self, i.e. the part **math questions** tells you that Stack Overflow isn't the correct site.

After reading the question body, it still seems to me that the question is more math related than programming related. So once again I will say that Stack Overflow isn't the correct site.

You can ask questions about bitwise/logical operators on Stack Overflow but the context must be programming. Solving an equation isn't.

**My conclusion:** 
The question seems to be off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Whether the question is on-topic for Math.StackExchange I can't tell.

Comment: Solving equations *with code* tho is totally on-topic.

Comment: @KennyEvitt Agree - That would make the context programming and therefore on-topic. However, there seems to be no such thing in OP's question.