# Boolean logic questions are general computer questions?

Tags: discussion, tags, closed-questions

I noticed a rep change the other day and so looked at my profile to see what had happened.

It turns out that [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52351893/15498) had not just been closed as "off topic" (belonging on Super User) but had also been deleted.

I don't expect general computer users to necessarily be experts in boolean logic. I  notice that the Super User site has neither of the tags ([boolean-logic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/boolean-logic) and [boolean-expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/boolean-expression)) that were applied to this question, and whilst they're not massive tags, they do appear to be active here on this site.

I could also understand if people were just generally closing down a "homework" question and had picked an odd close reason. But I felt the user had done enough to explain their own efforts. Text here:

> I am trying to minimize a Boolean Expression : (A+B)(~A+C) which minimizes to AC+~AB. Can someone help me out to give the solution to this. I am stuck in the mid after opening the brackets and *getting an extra term BC*.

(My *emphasis*)

It felt clear to me exactly where they were stuck on this (see my emphasis above) so I provided an answer, the OP seemed happy enough (I can't remember if they accepted the answer but I don't pester people for accepts - enough people do that that most people will eventually learn it and revisit their early questions).

So, a) Was this question off topic and b) Was Super User the right site for them to be redirected to? Is there a more education oriented site that would have been a better fit for them?

Comment: SO contibutors should not be setting, assisting with, correcting or marking boolean algebra homework.  That is what teachers do, and SO should be helping only after 'Computer Science 101' leaves off.  I can agree that trying to migrate it to 'Super User' is well.... [CoC filter] 'strange'.

Comment: Related: [*Do bitwise/logical operator math questions belong on Stack Overflow or Math.StackExchange?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/367807/2751851)

Comment: It got to [a chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/search?q=52351893). Twice no less, at least the first one couldn't think of a valid close reason either and never actually VtC-ed himself. The OP doesn't look like a student, works for a big company in India. I never really understood why such questions are disliked so much. But I have an EE degree, makes it pretty hard to understand how anyone can be an effective programmer without understanding logic well enough :)

Comment: Regardless of which site would be the "best", this seems like a typical example of "too localized", or "too broad". This would be much better answered in a canonical post on the subject. Helping individual users with this type of homework seems unlikely to be helpful to anyone else (in that it would be both hard to find and possibly hard to apply to another situation).

Comment: In terms of this particular question, it should be closed as "too broad" / "gimme teh codez" rather than "general computing" - please see [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: @Dukeling The main problem in my opinion is that it's "gimme teh codez"

Comment: @EJoshuaS - do you think if I'd discussed, agreed, and copied the first para from my answer in to form part of the question instead it would have been a better question? I could see "I'm stuck at this step" and they needed to know what to do to move forward from that step. I admit I went further and also supplied another step that may have been non-obvious to them but since they already knew what the final answer should be (and the two steps are mirror images) I didn't feet it was too far.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever How often would there be someone who needs to simplify exactly `(A+B)(~A+C)`? It's more a case of needing to know all the things they can try rather than having the solution to one specific case involving one specific set of techniques.

Comment: @Dukeling - yes, but even something as limited as "How do I identify and eliminate redundant terms when simplifying boolean expressions" sounds like it's going to run straight into too broad territory.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever We tend to be a lot more lenient about the broadness of canonical posts.

Answer (score 23):

**Is the question on-topic on SO?**

In my opinion: No. It is about boolean algebra, which is a fundamental part of Computer Science, but is not directly related to programming. There can be question which involve both, boolean algebra and programming which might be on-topic, but minimizing a boolean expression isn't.

**Is the "General Computing" close reason correct?**

No. Boolean algebra is definitely something that an average (or even an experienced) computer **user** is not capable of. I would have gone with a custom close reason and would have suggested [Computer Science SE](https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), where such question should be on-topic.

**Is the question in general a good question?**

No. Op states that they have a problem after opening the brackets but don't show that. The problem could be a calculation mistake during opening which we will never be able to find without seeing what they did. For me, this looks similar to a "I have a problem in my code" question that doesn't show the code.

Comment: They stated that they had the extra term BC which I felt was "just enough" to salvage it from being a bad question - I could tell exactly where they were stuck from that.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever still off-topic though